# UI5 Can we create json model using just the entity type metadata from a service model

Tags: odata, sapui5

I want to create a model and set it as one of the global model in oninit method of component. I have a sap gateway odata service with just an entity type and do NOT have corresponding entityset.

My ui5 project has manifest.json with default model and component.js Is it possible to to create a model using just the metadata.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you initialize the model, all you need is the metadata for initializing the SAPUI5 OData model. As long as the metadata is syntactically valid it should not be a problem. The EntitySets are only required when you assign an aggregation to a control using this model.

Update:

Its possible to get the details of the metadata from the model & create a new JSON model with it.

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel("http://services.odata.org/V2/OData/OData.svc");
var metaModel = oModel.getMetaModel();

var oEntitySet = metaModel.getODataEntitySet("Products");   //For getting properties of an Entity Set

//For Entity, you may have to provide the service namespace along, in this case ODataDemo
var oEntity = metaModel.getODataEntityType("ODataDemo.Product");
```

The oEntity object will look something like this

[image: oEntity Object]

With this you can create a new JSON model as

```
var oODataJSONModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({"Selection" : oEntity.property });
```

Here is a [working example](http://jsbin.com/felefubuti/edit?html,console)

Comment: I was able to create a model successfully refer to oData service in onInit() method. Now I want to create a JSON model of an EntityType with in the oData model. I have added a screen shot of component.js onInit()  to my original message above just to give a clear picture.

Comment: So you want to create a model from the Metadata response of the OData service?

Comment: Yes. that is correct. not sure if that is possible or not. There are lot of fields ( 20+) in that entitytype. trying to avoid locally building all the fields in JSON model.

Comment: This is really interesting. @Stephen - Will adding a "datasource" to manifest have the same effect as using the metadata to create a model manually? Can I get a faster app if I create the model myself?

Comment: Thank @Stephen . I have tried your code example here [link](http://jsbin.com/yozowep/edit?html,console,output) . I am not sure what I did wrong. I am seeing type errors in console.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I had a typo in the code, the initial declaration should be ODataModel instead of the ODataMetaModel. Updated my answer. You can check the example here. @Sid, Yes adding the datasource to the manifest will have the same effect. Creating a model in the code will be faster than waiting for the OData service to complete

Comment: Thanks @Stephen for your time. now there is a new error [here](http://jsbin.com/yozowep/edit?html,console,output) Cannot read property 'getObject' of null.

Comment: @SriniRao The error is due to a Cross-origin request. Use this url in your model declaration  https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://services.odata.org/V2/OData/OData.svc

Comment: It is working great after using cors url as suggested by @Stephen S. For community purpose [example](http://jsbin.com/cufuzekela/edit?html,console,output) here.